# When reading from app.config .showing error in main program

Tags: c#

when I am calling it from app.config .it showing error in next part of code

```
static void Main(string[] args)

   {

   string Sys = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appsettings"];

   string[] sys1 = Sys.Split(',');

  List<string> symbols = new List<string>();

      foreach (string item in sys1)

        {

      symbols.Add(item);

        }

}
string idExchangeId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["idExchangeId"];

        Logger.Write("########## Commodities Control Rate Puller Program starting up ########## ");

        session = new RatePullerSession(hostname, 
                                            port, 
                                            username, 
                                            password, 
                                            idExchangeId, 
                                            symbols, 
                                            userModeOutputTokens);
        session.Initialize();

        session.Logon();
        session.SubscribeSymbols();            
        session.querySubscribedSymbols();
        session.ListenStreamingUpdates();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what error do you get and what line of code is causing it?

Comment: you've a lot of unbalanced closing braces in there

Comment: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appsettings"];  needs to be ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["<named key of setting>"];

Comment: you can found solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766654/appsettings-get-value-from-config-file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to retrieve all the values you are keeping in Configuration.AppSettings. To do this try using ConfigurationManager.Appsettings.AllKeys then you can do:

```
        var settings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Keys;

        foreach (string setting in settings)
        {
            symbols.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[setting]);
        }
```