# Multiple int values in config key C# XML

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, key, application-settings

I want to add multiple int values to my Settings.
So far I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="DigiPortServer1" 
type="Configuration.Helpers.MultipleValuesSelection, Configuration.Helpers"   
requirePermission="false"/>
</configSections>

<DigiPortServer1>
<add key="3" value="3"></add>
<add key="4" value="4"></add>
<add key="5" value="5"></add>
<add key="6" value="6"></add>
<add key="7" value="7"></add>
<add key="8" value="8"></add>
<add key="9" value="9"></add>
<add key="10" value="10"></add>
<add key="11" value="11"></add>
<add key="12" value="12"></add>
<add key="13" value="13"></add>
<add key="14" value="14"></add>
<add key="15" value="15"></add>
<add key="16" value="16"></add>
<add key="17" value="17"></add>
<add key="18" value="18"></add>
</DigiPortServer1>
</configuration>
```

Is this right? I have found many questions considerung multiple String values. How can I access these values? I would like to save these into a int array or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would modify your file to be in this way. So it will be easier to access and to work with. This way you can easily access those features by writing `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["3"].ToString();`
Note that your file wasn´t having the keys associated with any values. I added the value atribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="DigiPortServer1"    
type="Configuration.Helpers.MultipleValuesSelection, Configuration.Helpers" 
requirePermission="false"/>
</configSections>

<appSettings>
<add key="3" value="3"></add>
<add key="4" value="4"></add>
<add key="5" value="5"></add>
<add key="6" value="6"></add>
<add key="7" value="7"></add>
<add key="8" value="8"></add>
<add key="9" value="9"></add>
<add key="10" value="10"></add>
<add key="11" value="11"></add>
<add key="12" value="12"></add>
<add key="13" value="13"></add>
<add key="14" value="14"></add>
<add key="15" value="15"></add>
<add key="16" value="16"></add>
<add key="17" value="17"></add>
<add key="18" value="18"></add>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks good, although I would like to use these values as int values. Any other solution than parsing it from string to int?

Comment: Simple, instead of casting as string, cast as int Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["3"])

Comment: you can cast as the data type you need

Comment: Actually your suggestion does not create any error, but as a console output I only get 0.   
Can you spot any mistake?         
int x = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["3"]);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
int z = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["4"]);
            Console.WriteLine(z);

Comment: It should not. It´s appSettings basics. You sure you are accesing the file correctly?

Comment: Nope, I am not really sure now. The XML is in my App.config.

Comment: look at how to work it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766654/appsettings-get-value-from-config-file

Comment: try the full reference: System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["3"]

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot as this was a correct answer and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

You could access the configuration section value using the ConfigurationManager GetSection method.

```
var section = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("DigiPortServer1") as System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection;
        var value = section["keyname"];
```

If section is the name value pair then cast with above type (NameValueCollection) or you can use own type to cast.