# How to push configuration values from Asp.Net Core MVC 2.0 config file to React TypeScript client script?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an application on `ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0` using `React Template`.
I have propertie in config file on server side - `SiteURL`. I need to push it to client `TypeScript`, and don`t understand how can I make it?

I tried to push them throw `Home/Index` file by placing in the last script

```
SiteProps.SiteURL= "http://mysiteurl.org"
```

and on client I make

```
export var SiteProps: { SiteURL: string } = {SiteURL: ""};
```

and import this file on boot

But testing this property on console I see

> Uncaught ReferenceError: SiteProps is not defined

I think that `JavaScript` did't see my propertie from `TypeScript` context.

The question is how to make this code work, and what is the best practice to push const values (properties) to client `TypeScript` code.

Comment: If you are Server Side Rendering or app you could pass it as a prop to the main component, otherwise, if no SSR is being made you'll have to hard code it in the front-end code.

Another approach could be using your webpack configuration to read the web.config and create a variable with the value.

Comment: On server renders only Home/Index and i can not push values directly to main component from C#, and it builds on TypeScript compiler and webpack to  complete js script, so i can't pass value using razor, as i think. Hardcode on client is varian but Last variant, because i don`t like two places of identical config. Webpack aproach is interesting, but How?

Comment: And i found one way. not so hard to make what I need. Using `div` and `json`, see my answer. But loooking other ways.

Answer (score 3):

I found solution to make this line on `Home/Index`:

```
<div id="site-props" style="display: none;">@ViewBag.PropsJSON</div>
```

Where `PropsJSON` is `JSON` string of my configuration.
After it i initialize my clientscript configuration using this code:

```
function ImportProps() {
    var ell = document.getElementById('site-props');
    var jsontext = ell!.innerText;
    SiteProps = JSON.parse(jsontext);
}
```

Comment: could you please explain a bit how did you add the functionality for getting the appsettings value?

Comment: @Mostafa  You can look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766654/appsettings-get-value-from-config-file

Comment: Are you using `UseSpa()`? I am, and `index.html` is hard-coded. No .Net-side rendering can be done.

Comment: @JariTurkia the other way is to override settings.js file when application start and to ref it in index.html .

Comment: And one more way is to fetch seetings from controller on the fly

Comment: And more one. From TS set `window.settings` and then to use it from any place.

Answer (score 0):

Some more ways how to solve it.

### One.

When application starts to rewrite file "mysetting.js" with actual settings and to ref this file in `index.html`

**mysetting.js**

```
var settings = {
  SiteName: "MySite",
  SiteApi: "http://site.api"
}
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="mysetting.js"></script>
```

### Two.

In `Home/Index` set window.settings in script block

```
window.settings = {
  SiteName: "MySite",
  SiteApi: "http://site.api"
}
```

and it should be available from all code.

### Three.

After client application starts get all settings with fetch request from server on the fly, and get result as JSON object, and set it somewhere to static.

```
fetch("api/Settings/getSettings").
   then( /* set data to static */ )
```

Where you initialize your client code.