# how to display a value that is stored in appsettings of web.config file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
<appSettings>
<add key="pat_ins_suc" value="patient registration successful."/>
</appSettings>
```

i want to display the value using JavaScript alert() function in the browser using one method call.

```
public void display()
{
string msg = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pat_ins_suc"];
}
```

how to pass the string msg inside the alert() function so that it will display in the web browser.

Comment: You can get this value in C# code and can pass it value to javascriot function but in javascript you can't get value of Appsetting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AppSettings get value from .config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766654/appsettings-get-value-from-config-file)

Comment: this is not duplicate. my question is after retrieving the value how to display this value using alert function of javascript. i think you can understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<appSettings>
<add key="insert" value="patient inserted successfully"/>
</appSettings>
```

In the web.config file inside the  write this code
in the C# code file write the code for calling the JavaScript code

```
dispay()
{
hdn.Value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["insert"];
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", 
"msg()", true);
}
```

in the .aspx page write the JavaScript function to get the result

```
<script>
    function msg()
    {
        alert('<%= hdn.Value%>');
    }
</script>
```

this will display the message that is stored in appsettings of web.config file using the alert function of the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

try this. i hope this helps

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var patinMessage= '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pat_ins_suc"]%>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In Page Load event store the config value in hidden fields using Config Manager.
2. Retire from hidden fields using JQuery.
3. JQuery function function GetWebConfigVal(){ var hiddenFildsVal=$("#hiddenFiledId").val(); alert(hiddenFildsVal); }

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Razor view then this will help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pat_ins_suc"]';
alert(url);
</script>
```