# Read Connection String Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-config

Curious to know if there is a way to read in some parameters of the connectionstring within the web.config file? For example, if I had a *Settings* page on my website for administrators only, and one of the views within there was to show the name, providerName, and connectionString... could I do this?

```
<add 
name="DbConnectionString" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
connectionString="Data Source=yourservernamehere.net 
/>
```

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnectionString"]` returns an [object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.connectionstringsettings) with those properties.

Comment: Thanks madrefiection! I thought I was going crazy here, because i had tried this and it didn't work. Another member just let me know that the using system.configuration may not have been declared, which it wasn't. I'll mark this as resolved now.

Comment: Also if you use app settings, you can use 

    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766654/appsettings-get-value-from-config-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Curious to know if there is a way to read in some parameters of the connectionstring within the web.config file?

**Yes**.

> For example, if I had a Settings page on my website for administrators only, and one of the views within there was to show the name, providerName, and connectionString... could I do this?

**Yes.** You can do the same:

```
using System.Configuration;
string yourConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourConnectionStringNameInYourConfigFile"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

First step was to ensure `using System.Configuration` is declared.

```
SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnectionString"].ToString());

lblDBConnName.Text = dbConn.DataSource.ToString();
```

Comment: Don't use `ToString()` to get the connection string.  Use the `ConnectionString` property. It's reasonable that the implementation of `ToString` may change, even if only subtly, but the `ConnectionString` property won't because that's its exact purpose.