# Dynamically read user settings from other application without knowing what settings the file holds C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, service, app-config

I need to read/write to an exe.config file without knowing before-hand what settings the file has. I am using the AppSettingsSection class, but the Settings collection is empty when the exe.config actually contains about 20 user settings. Here is the code I am using to access the application settings

```
string path = @"C:\Projects\App1.exe";
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(path);
AppSettingsSection appSettingSection = config.AppSettings;
```

It gets the config but the appSettingSection.Settings is empty when it really should have about 20 items. Am I missing something or is this not possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AppSettings get value from .config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766654/appsettings-get-value-from-config-file)

Comment: @AMA No, because config.AppSettings is empty. And I also do not know the Keys before hand.