# I tried to create my own helper class for saving and loading the settings but the loading part the list inside is empty. why the list is empty?

Tags: c#, winforms

i know it's a bit long but it's all connected.

in form1 top I created this class:

```
public class SettingControlPair
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public Control Control { get; set; }
}
```

then created this list variable and a variable for the configurationhelper class:

```
private List<SettingControlPair> settingControlPairs = new List<SettingControlPair>();
private ConfigurationHelper configurationHelper;
```

in the form1 constructor I'm initializing the configurationhelper and also calling the ConfigurationLoading method:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Initialize your module classes here
    selectedImagePath = string.Empty;
    imageProcessor = new ImageProcessor(selectedImagePath);
    fileHandler = new FileHandler();

    configurationHelper = new ConfigurationHelper(settingControlPairs);

    if (textBoxLensSize.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        LensCropRectWidth = 10;
    }

    InitializeUI();
    configurationHelper.LoadConfiguration();
}
```

example of how I'm using it to save:

```
private void textBoxLensSize_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Perform real-time input validation
    if (int.TryParse(textBoxLensSize.Text, out int width))
    {
        // Valid integer input
        if (width >= 10)
        {
            LensCropRectWidth = width; // Update the property
            labelCroppedImagesCount.Focus();

            configurationHelper.SaveConfiguration("LensSize", width, textBoxLensSize);
        }
        else
        {
            // Show a message if the value is less than 10
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value greater than or equal to 10.");
            textBoxLensSize.Text = 10.ToString(); // Revert to the previous value
            labelCroppedImagesCount.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

this is the saving line:

```
configurationHelper.SaveConfiguration("LensSize", width, textBoxLensSize);
```

and last the ConfigurationHelper class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static Images_Cropping.Form1;

namespace Images_Cropping
{
    public class ConfigurationHelper
    {
        private List<SettingControlPair> settingControlPairs;

        public ConfigurationHelper(List<SettingControlPair> settingControlPairs)
        {
            this.settingControlPairs = settingControlPairs;
        }

        public void LoadConfiguration()
        {
            foreach (var pair in settingControlPairs)
            {
                var value = Properties.Settings.Default[pair.Key];
                if (value != null)
                {
                    pair.Value = value;

                    if (pair.Control is TextBox textBox)
                    {
                        textBox.Text = value.ToString();
                    }
                    else if (pair.Control is CheckBox checkBox)
                    {
                        if (bool.TryParse(value.ToString(), out bool isChecked))
                        {
                            checkBox.Checked = isChecked;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (pair.Control is NumericUpDown numericUpDown)
                    {
                        if (decimal.TryParse(value.ToString(), out decimal numericValue))
                        {
                            numericUpDown.Value = numericValue;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (pair.Control is ComboBox comboBox)
                    {
                        comboBox.SelectedItem = value;
                    }
                    else if (pair.Control is TrackBar trackBar)
                    {
                        if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out int trackBarValue))
                        {
                            trackBar.Value = trackBarValue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public bool SaveConfiguration(string key, object value, Control control)
        {
            try
            {
                // Save the configuration setting
                Properties.Settings.Default[key] = value;

                // Add the key, object value, and control to the list
                settingControlPairs.Add(new SettingControlPair
                {
                    Key = key,
                    Value = value,
                    Control = control
                });

                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                return true; // Save operation succeeded
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle any exceptions related to saving the configuration
                Console.WriteLine("Error saving configuration: " + ex.Message);
                return false; // Save operation failed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that the List settingControlPairs is empty.
and then when trying to loop over the list in the LoadConfiguration method ir does nothing because the List is empty.

the reason that the list is empty is because I init the configurationHelper in form1 constructor with the list but the list is empty:

```
configurationHelper = new ConfigurationHelper(settingControlPairs);
```

the list settingControlPairs is empty and so is empty in the LoadingConfiguration method.

how can i fix the logic problem that the list will not be empty ?

Answer (score 1):

The string probably is just empty not null, when it is read from the config. So to fix your issue, one of the following checks in the if block (located within the foreach loop of the load method) should help:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
```

Alternatively you can use:

```
if(value?.Length > 0)
```

E.G.:

```
public void LoadConfiguration()
{
    foreach (var pair in settingControlPairs)
    {
        var value = Properties.Settings.Default[pair.Key];
        if (value?.Length > 0)
        {
            pair.Value = value;

            if (pair.Control is TextBox textBox)
            {
                textBox.Text = value.ToString()
[...]
```

Comment: but the List is empty already in the foreach line:  foreach (var pair in settingControlPairs) so it will never get inside the loop.  the list is not null it's empty count 0.

Comment: He is providing a list. If I understood correctly. He did initialize the keys beforehand and is no fetching the values from a settings file?

Comment: right.  i think this is the problem.  the list get init in the form1 constructor and get filled when saving but then next time when running the application the list get init again and is empty.  i need some how to find a way to withdraw the saved data from the settings file to the list.

Comment: ok in this case, you might consider using the configuration manager class to fetch your settings. As this is a win forms app, it should have a app.config file that can be used to store your settings. This thread explains how to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766654/appsettings-get-value-from-config-file

Otherwise you need to read out the config file and add each SettingControlPair to the list. Or you could use a settings class, which contains variables for all keys. Then fetch the values for each key by hardcoding the key name.

Comment: how about creating my own json class and file that will store(save) and load the settings ?  is that sound logic ?  to create from scratch my own settings file.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, one thing that could explain the behavior is if, in `InitializeComponent`, events like `TextBox.TextChanged` are being subscribed to before that control's *initial* value is set, because then those initial (blank) values could be being saved into the configuration and then when you load the configuration you get nothing.

So, for example, if you had a form containing these controls and wanted it to be populated with the same values the next time the app starts, here is one way you could go about it that would fix all the issues you're having.

[image: sample form]

---

I think your idea of writing a Json file (to the user's AppData folder) is a good one. And just to be on the safe side, try doing things in this order:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    string configPath { get; } =
        Path.Combine(
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
            Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name,
            "config.json"
    );
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Restore values BEFORE subscribing to events
        LoadConfiguration();
        // NOW you can safely subscribe.
        SubscribeToEvents();
    }
    Dictionary<string, object> ConfigurationHelper { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

---

**Loading the configuration from the Json file**

```
private void LoadConfiguration()
{
    if (File.Exists(configPath))
    {
        ConfigurationHelper =
            JsonConvert
            .DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(File.ReadAllText(configPath));
        foreach (var key in ConfigurationHelper.Keys)
        {
            if (Controls[key] is Control control)
            {
                if (control is TextBox textBox)
                {
                    if (ConfigurationHelper.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
                    {
                        textBox.Text = value.ToString();
                    }
                }
                else if (control is NumericUpDown numeric)
                {
                    if (ConfigurationHelper.TryGetValue(key, out var o) && int.TryParse($"{o}", out int value))
                    {
                        numeric.Value = value;
                    }
                }
                else if (control is ComboBox comboBox)
                {
                    if (ConfigurationHelper.TryGetValue(key, out var o) && int.TryParse($"{o}", out int value))
                    {
                        comboBox.SelectedIndex = value;
                    }
                }
                else if (control is TrackBar trackBar)
                {
                    if (ConfigurationHelper.TryGetValue(key, out var o) && int.TryParse($"{o}", out int value))
                    {
                        trackBar.Value = value;
                    }
                }
                else if (control is CheckBox checkBox)
                {
                    if (ConfigurationHelper.TryGetValue(key, out var o) && bool.TryParse($"{o}", out bool value))
                    {
                        checkBox.Checked = value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(configPath));
        ConfigurationHelper = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
}
```

**Subscribe to change events**

Make sure that you go through the Designer.cs file. Either remove the existing handlers for control change events like `TextChanged` or `SelectionIndexChanged` entirely, *or* at least go through those handlers making sure they don't do any writing to the configuration file. There's a real possibility that these can cause a race condition that could contribute to the problem you're seeing. *To be clear, it's perfectly ok to subscribe to an event multiple times to multiple handlers. If you choose to leave the existing handlers in place, don't let them write to your `SaveConfiguration` method.*

---

After the configuration is already loaded, subscribe to the events this way instead:

```
    private void SubscribeToEvents()
    {
        foreach (var control in IterateControls(Controls))
        {
            if (control is TextBox textBox)
            {
                // You're still free to subscribe to these events
                // in other places for different purposes.
                textBox.TextChanged += (sender, e) => 
                    SaveConfiguration(textBox, textBox.Text);
            }
            else if (control is NumericUpDown numeric)
            {
                numeric.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => 
                    SaveConfiguration(numeric, numeric.Value);
            }
            else if (control is ComboBox comboBox)
            {
                comboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted += (sender, e) => 
                    SaveConfiguration(comboBox, comboBox.SelectedIndex);
            }
            else if (control is TrackBar trackBar)
            {
                trackBar.ValueChanged += (sender, e) =>
                    SaveConfiguration(trackBar, trackBar.Value);
            }
            else if (control is CheckBox checkBox)
            {
                checkBox.CheckedChanged += (sender, e) => 
                    SaveConfiguration(checkBox, checkBox.Checked);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Save individual control changes**

When changes occur, just serialize the dictionary. As written, it's not terribly efficient. Every keystroke in any textbox writes the entire file. So optimize by waiting for changes to settle and maybe writing the config file asynchronously or even just doing it when the app closes.

```
    private void SaveConfiguration(Control control, object value)
    {
        ConfigurationHelper[control.Name] = value.ToString();
        // Save every change OR: - Save on app close? - Save after time delay (consolidate rapid changes)?
        File.WriteAllText(configPath, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ConfigurationHelper));
    }
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/configuration-manager.git) this example.